# Working with Dates in Java

Tags: java

I need to work with dates and I wasn't sure how to go about that in Java since I have never done it before.

I am pulling dates from the Excel file and they can be retrieved in the Data format which would represent the date.

Ex:

1. 2/1/2010
2. 5/12/2011
3. 8/15/2011
4. 9/1/2011
5. 9/1/2011

All my codes are pretty irrelvent to the question, but I am setting up a getter/setter method:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

So my question is this, in what way when I am pulling the data from Excel:

```
    temp.setDate((row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue());
```

I can set the limit so it only retrieves data from x amount of months. 8, 12, et.. from the last month/year displayed in the file, instead of going back all the way to 2010? I can provide more details if needed.

Edit: This is what I have now:

```
   import java.util.Date;
    Date date;
   date = row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue();
```

It shows: Tue June 01 00:00:00

I don't care about Tuesday or 00:00:00, I just have a whole list of data and I only want to show x amount of months.

Edit: I figured it out. :)

Comment: Your question is very unclear.I don't understand what you want to achieve, and you don't say what this `Data` class is.

Comment: There is no data class, I just want to store the value of date is a data format from the Excel, or would strings be easier?

Comment: Wait so is "data" just a repeated typo of "date" or is there actually a `Data` type being used here?

Comment: I've updated the the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with DateFormat.class fo parse the cell, or use a Calendar to put Day Month Year

**EDIT**

You can also use *Calendar.class*

```
final String[] tabDate = {"2/1/2010", "5/12/2011", "8/15/2011",
                           "9/1/2011", "9/1/2011"};
// Extract field's value
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// Parse the list of stringDate
for (final String string : tabDate) {
    System.out.println("Input string: " + string);
    final String[] shortDate = string.split("/");

   // Build Calendar
    c.set(Integer.valueOf(shortDate[2]), Integer.valueOf(shortDate[0]),
        Integer.valueOf(shortDate[1]));

    // Extract date as you like
    System.out.format("%25s  : %d/%d/%d\t%s\n\n", c.getTime(),
        c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE),
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Console :

```
Input string: 2/1/2010
Mon Mar 01 09:09:48 CET 2010  : 2/1/2010    1267430988109

Input string: 5/12/2011
Sun Jun 12 09:09:48 CEST 2011  : 5/12/2011  1307862588109

Input string: 8/15/2011
Thu Sep 15 09:09:48 CEST 2011  : 8/15/2011  1316070588109

Input string: 9/1/2011
Sat Oct 01 09:09:48 CEST 2011  : 9/1/2011   1317452988109

Input string: 9/1/2011
Sat Oct 01 09:09:48 CEST 2011  : 9/1/2011   1317452988109
```

Comment: Can you show me a quick way to parse it? is it (Date?) because write now it won't let me do it with string and using double shows a weird value. Nevermind, I got it. df.parse(myString), but still how am I suppose to compare it and get only the last x months?

Comment: @user1452530 c.get(Calendar.MONTH) give you the last month in the year . If you are looking for last five months period : you have tp create a Calendar with the date of the beginning of the period, and compare  c.getTimeInMillis().

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague, but if you are using Excel I have found it very beneficial to save the file as a 'filename.csv'.  This format very easy to work with, it is comma delimited going across and newlines going down.  If you are periodically checking the month, it would be easy to ensure that you only go x months backwards.

Comment: File is already in excel format and I am wokring with multiple stuff from it, its just the dates that are bothering me. They are listed as m/day/year is that string or integer?

Comment: That looks like it would be a string, if you use the StringTokenizer class, when you take the string in as m/day/year you can break it into three strings m, day, and year then convert those strings into integers.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a doable approach.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the dates accordingly using the SimpleDateFormat class. The result is a date object.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "M/d/yyyy" );
Date date = df.parse(row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue());
```

Then:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

will return you an object ob type Calendar, where you can set the date by

```
cal.setTime(date);
```

Finally your loop reading the Excel file can determine according to the calendar object, if the date should be included / further processed by using:

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // e.g. 11 for Nov
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // e.g. 2011
```

Comment: It is saying that the method parse(String) in the type Date formatis not applicable for the arguments (Date).

Comment: `getDateCellValue` is already returning a `Date` - the OP isn't asking about parsing.